# Protecting Against Inrush Current

Tags: power-supply, power, ups

In my apartment, the main circuit breaker has a very low amperage limit of 5A (220V), with a maximum power limit of 1300W. Therefore, about 75% of the time I plug in my PC power plug, the inrush current of the power supply always trip the breaker. Obviously this is very annoying (albeit I only unplug my PC when doing maintenances).

I know, better power supply unit has better inrush current protection, but I believe my current power supply is decent enough (a Seasonic M12-II 520W) and the problem lies in the low amperage of my apartment's MCB. However, I cannot change that unit to a higher rated one due to local regulations (it's sealed and breaking the seals is breaking the laws). So, is there any solution for this problem? Will using something like a UPS works?

Comment: Your entire apartment is limit to 1,100VA? (5 * 220 = 1,100) Honestly, I'd say you don't have sufficient electrical capacity to run a typical desktop.

Comment: No, it's just for my room. Each room have different MCB.

Comment: Than bring a lengthy cord from another room. Plug your monitor in one room, PC in another. I would although suggest adding a capacitor to power plug, but that requires skills.